# Counting evens in a two-dimensional list?

Tags: python

Hey guys I'm trying to make a program that counts the evens in a two-dimensional list. The program I made so far is not returning what I want it to.

```
def Evens(x):
    count = 0
    x = len(x)
    for a in range(x):
        if a%2 == 0:
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

that keeps returning 2 for the list `Evens([[1,3],[1,9,7,1,3],[13]])` when I want it to return 4. I tried everything but it seems to not be working correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of even numbers in all sub-lists? I don't see any even numbers in the sample input. `len(x)` is 3 in your example (3 sublists, total) and `range(3)` is `[0,1,2]` which contains two evens.

Comment: Why you want it to return 4? It is returning what you are asking it to return.

Comment: Why wouldn't it return `0`?

Comment: Sorry I put in the wrong list, I want it to return the number of even numbers in each list so for a list like `[[1,4,3],[12,0,7,10,3],[13]]` it would return 4 because there is 4 even numbers in that list.

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're encountering is that you are checking the indices to see if they are even, not the values. You're also not checking in the sublists.

More straightforward, IMO, is to do this:

```
import itertools
def evens(x):
    return sum(a % 2 == 0 for a in itertools.chain.from_iterable(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually iterate over the sublists.

```
def evens(l):
    count = 0
    for l2 in l:
        for i in l2:
            if i%2 == 0:
                count += 1
    return count
```

Or you can you can take a much simpler approach.

```
def evens(l):
    return sum(i%2==0 for l2 in l for i in l2)
```

The second approach uses the fact that in an integer context, `True == 1` and `False == 0`, so you would get the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate over all the sublists:

```
In [34]: l = [[1,4,3],[12,0,7,10,3],[13]]

In [35]: sum(n%2 == 0 for sub in l for n in sub)
Out[35]: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the elements in each sublist as well:

```
def count_evens(l):
    total = 0

    for l2 in l:
        for item in l2:
            if item % 2 == 0:
                total += 1

    return total
```

What you were doing before was iterating over the number of sublists (i.e. `[0, 1, 2, 3]` for a list with `4` elements). Your code was working, but it wasn't working properly.

Comment: Thank you, thank you! I feel stupid for missing that. Code is working perfect now!